# Is my reasoning about existence of a distributional solution correct?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory

Does the equation $x''+\lambda x' - x = \phi$, where $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\phi\in\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}^N)$ is a given arbitrary test function, always have a solution in a distributional sense?

I think that the answer is affirmative. And the reason is because the Malgrange-Ehrenpreis theorem guarantees the existence of the fundamental solution, let's say $T$. So then, the distributional solution of $x''+\lambda x' - x = \phi$ is $T\ast \phi$. Is this reasoning correct?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: So, every linear coefficients differential equation has solution in the sense of distributions... only when the coefficients are not constants, one may have no distributional solution as shows lewy's example. Am I right?

Comment: Even linear PDE's with constant coefficients have solutions. This is a basic theorem in PDE. You can find a proof in Rudin's FA.